# Configure multiple template resolvers for a single Spring Boot instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to configure a second template resolver to be used by Thymeleaf. I also want the default resolver which looks under the `templates` folder but whatever I try I only end up with a single resolver.

In my project there is already a yaml configuration file which contains:

```
thymeleaf:
    mode: LEGACYHTML5
    cache: false
```

As a first step I've tried to add a configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ThymeleafConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware
{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/public/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

But I never see a second resolver in `org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository`, just the default.

I've further tried omdifying the YAML file with the following:

```
thymeleaf:
    -
      mode: LEGACYHTML5
      cache: false
      prefix: classpath:/public/
    -
      mode: LEGACYHTML5
      cache: false
      prefix: classpath:/templates/
```

But again I only get a single resolver created.

Anyone know how to do this or can see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add multiple resolvers, you could use [`engine.addTemplateResolver`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#addTemplateResolver-org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver-) instead of `engine.setTemplateResolver()` or use [`setTemplateResolvers()`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#setTemplateResolvers-java.util.Set-) which takes in a `Set`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ThymeleafConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware
{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolverPublic());
        engine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolverTemplates());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolverPublic() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/public/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        return resolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolverTemplates() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

P.S. On an other note if you want to use auto-configuration capabilities of Spring boot, you should avoid setting up your configuration manually (as you did in your configuration class) and instead just define properties in YAML which Spring Boot will use and will configure your template engine/resolvers. If you manually specify your configuration spring boot will not additionally configure the Thymeleaf engine/resolvers so the YAML properties w.r.t the configurations you defined will not be used i.e. you are basically overriding spring boots configurations.

Comment: OK I see the obvious error I made in the configuration class and I've changed it accordingly, but how would I do the same with just specifying it in the YAML file?

Comment: @Kerry I have only used the manual configuration for configuring multiple template resolvers. So I do not know the Spring Boot way of doing this. You can look at the Spring Boot Source Code to find a way to do this (if at all possible). Best way to check is by looking at [`ThymeleafAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java) file